# How can I change names of network interfaces shown in "ip addr show"

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, udev

Below is my partial output of `ip addr show`

```
10: ge4: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN
    link/ether 02:00:00:00:00:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: ge44: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN
    link/ether 02:00:00:00:00:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
12: ge45: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN
    link/ether 02:00:00:00:00:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

The output of `/sys/class/net` is as below

```
/sys/class/net> ll
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May 21 20:35 bond0 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/bond0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May 21 20:35 bond1 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/bond1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 21 20:35 bonding_masters
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May 21 20:34 eth0 -> ../../devices/fsl,dpaa.22/ethernet.23/net/eth0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May 21 20:34 eth1 -> ../../devices/fsl,dpaa.22/ethernet.24/net/eth1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May 21 20:34 eth2 -> ../../devices/fsl,dpaa.22/ethernet.25/net/eth2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May 21 20:44 ge4 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/ge4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May 21 21:15 ge44 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/ge44
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May 21 21:15 ge45 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/ge45
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May 21 20:34 gre0 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/gre0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May 21 20:34 lo -> ../../devices/virtual/net/lo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May 21 20:34 sit0 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/sit0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May 21 20:34 tunl0 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/tunl0
```

I tried adding a new rule file for udev and then restarted udev, but still the changes are not reflecting. 
I wish to change ge44 and ge45 names to something like "alpha0" and "alpha1".

Any hints how can I achieve this.

EDIT:

I changed the rule file as below

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/80-persistent-net.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="02:00:00:00:00:32", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="alpha0"

SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="02:00:00:00:00:33", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="alpha1"
```

Comment: What rule did you add?

Comment: @grawity - i changed the rule file and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

These look like virtual interfaces to me. Are you running any virtual machines on the system? Interfaces are typically defined in either `/etc/network/interfaces` (Debian style) or `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<ifname>` (Red Hat style) and in case of virtual interfaces (like the ones Xen creates) they may be found in the VMs' config files.

Comment: The changes of rule file are working and I am able to changes the interface names. What can I do to up/ down these interfaces. Do I need to create a ifcfg file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/

Comment: @vishram0709 I still don't know what system you are running and whether there are any virtual machines on it. That said, if it's a Red Hat-based distro (CentOS, Fedora, etc.), then yes, you most probably need to have a script in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` -- use an existing one as a template. Then `ifdown <interface>` and `ifup <interface>` bring the interface down or up, respectively.